# manually edit SQLite DB on AVD?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is it possible to edit the data in a virtual device's sqlite db? Or, can I export it, manipulate it, upload it?

It's the db for my own app, nothing nefarious! I just want to test things with certain data. 
thanks
NB: I know the location of the data.

Comment: Might want to check out http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, i personnaly use some sort of plugin you need to build your app with and then i go to `chrome://inspect`, i'll have my DB in the device list once my app is running (emulator or not, if it's a real phone, works as long as it's connected via usb for debugging).

The plugin name is `Stetho`.

You need to put this in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'       
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.3.1'       
}
```

And launch it this way in your code:

```
Stetho.initialize(Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
        .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this))
        .build());
```

After this like i said, emulator or not just launch your app and go to chrome://inspect then click on your device to open up the explorator, select sqlite DB or wichever DB type you use and navigate to your DB, then click on it.
You will then have access to all the tables etc and a console (similar to phpmyadmin's organization for example).

Really simple, i love Stetho.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can see or edit data in SQLite db from your device.
just add [this](https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android)
This is probably the finest and most useful code I have used. Need any help in this. I will be happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable](https://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable)

To get the database from your device without being root, just do

```
adb exec-out run-as <app-package-name> cat /data/user/0/<app-package-name>/databases/<database-name>.db > c:\tmp\test.db
```